Error: "command must be one of 'from', 'license', 'template', 'system', 'adapter', 'parameter', or 'message'" when creating a custom model in Ollama
I'm trying to create a custom model using Ollama, but when I run the following command:
ollama create my-custom-model

I get the following error message:
Error: (line 1): command must be one of "from", "license", "template", "system", "adapter", "parameter", or "message"

I’ve followed the instructions and created a Modelfile that looks like this:
from: llama3.2:latest
license: open
system: |
  You are AdelBot, a friendly chatbot designed by Adel. Your responses are concise and include emojis for clarity and fun! ✨
message:
  - role: user
    content: Who are you?
  - role: assistant
    content: I'm AdelBot, here to assist you with clear and concise answers. 

However, I’m still getting the same error.
Can someone help me understand why the error is happening and how to fix it?
Things I’ve Tried:

Double-checked the indentation in the Modelfile.
Ensured I’m using the correct commands (from, license, system, message).
Used the llama3.2:latest model, which is available on my system.

